# How to load assets from NPM-based package in PHP composer-based package?

Tags: javascript, php, npm, composer-php, assets

First of all: this is not the question about how to use NPM package as dependency of Composer package. This is not an issue: direct use of NPM or a composer plugin solves it.

Assuming we loaded NPM package as a dependency of Composer package (using create-package) we get roughly such structure:

```
Root
+-- node_modules
| +-- our_npm_package
|   +-- assets
|   | +-- our.css
|   +-- js
|     +-- bundle.js
+-- vendor
| +-- our
|   +-- package
+-- src
+-- tests
| composer.json
| package.json
| index.php
```

NPM package contains some web-assets (JS, CSS, images). We can use Browserify to bundle it together and just use bundle.js in our index.php . But the problem is that, in my view, this is bad way to do so. Browserify should bundle only JS while leaving CSS and images alone. Delivering CSS to browser through JS is really wrong use of technology: browser is quite capable to load CSS on its own. And this way it will work for browsers with JS disabled. Same story about images: browser can load and display them without help from JS.

So I concluded that Browserify (great package I should say) should be used only for JS and it produces nice bundle.js which we can call from our index.php

Here the core of the question: how to refer properly to these NPM-based assets in our Composer based PHP package? Of course we can use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/our_npm_package/assets/our.css">
```

but that's ugly and not reliable. I really want it to be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/our.css">
```

Same goes about bundle.js . I don't want to have:

```
<script src="/node_modules/our_npm_package/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

but rather

```
<script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

A lot of people just make scripts which create css and js folders in root folder and then knit-picking assets from NPM packages. Works but still ugly.

Some people (especially using frameworks) went further and use some sort of composer plugin which does copying automatically. In this case they specify which assets they want in their composer package. Better than just plain copy but still not really good.

What I would really want to have is declare assets in NPM package somehow. Then have Composer plugin/script to locate it in NPM package and symlink/copy them where they should be for use by PHP code. On top making sure that all assets needed by PHP are actually present.

I am on the verge of writing composer plugin for this purpose myself but I don't want to re-invent the wheel. Surely I am not the only one facing the issue of stitching up Composer PHP/NPM JS and I hope this issue was resolved in proper way already. I googled high and low over last three days and could not find anything decent.

Can you please tell me is there a simple way of resolving this issue? Single composer plugin may be considered as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Gulp/Grunt/other task runner to find other assets (images, stylesheets, etc.) and copy them to demanded destination.

```
/node_modules/our_npm_package/assets/our.css
```

could be copied to

```
/css/our.css
```

In Gulp, it could be achieved with something like following snippet

```
gulp.src('node_modules/**/*.css')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
```

This would copy all `.css` files anywhere in `node_modules/` to `css/`.

Comment: I think @user3713667 denied this solution in 4th paragraph from bottom (that begins with "Some people (especially using frameworks)").

Comment: Yes, using build system to copy the files is not the best approach. Build system should be aware of what is needed. If build system can collect this information from NPM package then it should be OK. But implicitly listing asset files in build script is really does not address my issue. Preference towards composer plugin is due to simplicity of deployment by third party - no need for gulp/grunt/ant or any other build system

Comment: @user3713667 but proposed approach is doing exactly this, that is copying files that are needed to destination that is prefered. What you want to do, is IMO different, because you want to take *any* path inside `node_modules/` and copy it. The problem with that is you don't know where are assets. Sure, you can find them in `node_modules/package-a/assets/css`, but `package-b` can have different structure.

Comment: NPM package may have *.css files which are not assets: such as pre-minified source css. I don't want them to pollute my /css folder. Therefore some way of manifesting them in NPM package is required. Then composer or some other build system may pick them up. NPM package developer has a knowledge what is asset and what is not and it should be expressed in some form. Copying everything from everywhere matching the mask is very brute force way of doing it. I don't deny that it works but it is not smart way of doing it.

Comment: In Yii2 they have asset class which basically manifests all assets required. But this only achieves "what composer package needs". I would like to have some way describing "what NPM package provides" and some tooling which matches them together at build/deploy time.

Comment: I agree, this is not smart way of doing it, but I don't imagine developers listing their assets in package.json or any other file. This is where build systems are used. Developer of package A creates tasks that builds required files and outputs them in some location.

Comment: Maybe if you use Bower? But then again, this is probably another thing that you want to avoid.

Comment: I guess main issue is that NPM being originally developed for server side things never considered manifesting web assets (same way as dependencies and tests are). Now when NPM used for client side issue of web assets is glaring. Browserify solved it by packing all together into bundle.js . But in my view proper manifestation of web assets is package.json is required. package.json is schemaless and so it may have web assets manifest which then may be consumed by some tool. Basically I am looking for such tool. Otherwise I will resort to writing it myself.

Comment: Bower is just a little brother of NPM - basically does the same thing and parallel use of it does not gain much. I would prefer to stick to NPM only given that it is quite powerful and can do everything bower can. Bower on its own will not resolve my issue.

Comment: I though so - but Bower (or other tools created for front-end assets) are as close as you can get to having manifests, at least as far as I know.